# *ngFor width content variable in Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using *ngFor to iterate several images as the background of each column in a row with Bootstrap. My question is: Can you control the width of each column? Let's say I have 10 images how can I control the width of each one? How do I assign that value?

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

my Array:

```
images: [ 'url1', 'url2', 'url3'...]
```

component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div *ngFor="let image of images" style="height: 400px; background-size: cover; background-position: center center" [style.background-image]="'url('+ image +')'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don' understand what you're asking. Yes, you can control the width: that's what the number in `col-lg-8` or `col-lg-4` does. It sets the width.

Comment: I want to place variable widths (as well as the example image) how can I do it?

Comment: Let's say you have an array of 10 images. How do you know which width to assign for each image?

Comment: Exact! It's what I need

Comment: That's what I need, control the width of each image.

Comment: What I don't understand is: on which criteria do you decide that the first is lg-8 and the second is lg-4? What makes you decide that? Is it random? Hard-coded? Based on some property of the URL of the image? Your question shows 6 images. If your array has 7, what should be the width of the last one and why?

Comment: if you inject ElementRef in the constructor, I imagine that you can use el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect . Of if you get in ViewChildren the images and in load on each image getBoundingClien of it you can use [ngClass] to give one or another class to your images

Comment: The condition for *ngFor loop is to have a pattern for looping. If you have some defined layout that repeats then definitely you can control *ngFor and width too.

Answer (score 0):

For the above layout, you're gonna need to make use of a nested array. Each sub-array would represent a row and will contain the columns that will be rendered. An example would work like this in the class:

```
rows = [
    [
         { url: url, class: class }, ...
    ], ...
]
```

And in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows" class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let column of row"[class]="column.class">
      <img [src]="column.url">
    </div>
</div>
```